# What is the payment schedule for Windows Store Developer payments?

Tags: marketplace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694058.aspx

> "Microsoft will pay you an amount equal to the Net Receipts for your
>   app, minus the Store Fee (the “App Proceeds”) as full compensation for
>   your app as made available to customers from the Windows Store, on a
>   monthly basis"

1. Please specify what the current practical behavior of "on a monthly basis" means. Eg, what is the current implemented payment schedule.
2. In the instance that Microsoft employees read this, please consider amending the public agreement to specify the expected behavior, eg similar to the Facebook agreement:

Microsoft will make payment of your Developer Balance approximately `X` number of days following the end of the `Timespan` period in which the transaction occurred, except as otherwise set forth herein.

Where `X` is the expected number of days after the particlar `Timespan` that transactions are grouped into. Eg, X is 2, and Timespan is monthly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vendor payment schedules. It should be addressed to the vendor instead. It is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Microsoft will not pay anything less than a $200(USD) check, so you must clear that hurdle first. Once you trigger over $200 a month steadily, you will get paid regularly on a monthly basis.

Also note that your cut is only 70% of the first $25,000 USD and then 80% on anything after.

As a developer, I do not make the $200 in a month, but it is generally only a day or two after I notice that I have hit the $200 threshold until my bank account gets creditted with the balance.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it doesn't answer the question of what the scheduling is apart form suggesting that it appears to occur at some point during the month when a sufficient amount has been accrued (as opposed to days after a time span as in the instance of Facebook (15 days post bimonthy), Google(15 days post monthly) and Apple(30 days post monthly)). I would like a specification as to the particular expected day that it occurs assuming that the requisite minimum is accrued on the first day.

Comment: I guess I am not familiar with the exact terminology you are expecting, but if you hit all of the requirements to get paid all of the time, you will get paid once per month. The exact date may vary from person to person, but it should be regular once you are eligible.